# can not access all google related sites on all browser, such as google.com, YouTube, gmail etc, but all other site works

Tags: web, browser, internet-connection

My computer can not access google.com, youtube, gmail on all browsers. I tried several solutions online, including reset dns to 8.8.8.8, reboot computer, restart dns, reset all ipconfig, none worked. I tried ping google.com and received request timed out. Other website works though.

Comment: instead of 8.8.8.8 try changing it to 8.8.4.4
Since when it stopped working?

Comment: Have you tried Twitter or Facebook? Are you in China / VPN'd into China?

Comment: I am in US. I changed the host file to VPN to china a while back, which causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if in your HOSTS file there is an entry for google or anything related to that.

In windows is in `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

In Linux is in `/etc/hosts`

if there is anything from google there, remove it and save the file, try rebooting the computer and it should work.

Comment: Do you happens to know why it causes the problem? The host file have been changed for a long time(more than a year I think) but it works fine till very recently.